# Can I use multiple OwningComponentBase<T> in my Blazor app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm using a template Blazor app to learn and I want to add a new page to CRUD a new table.
I created a new service for it.

The template already came with a CRUD-page and a service.
In its razor page it has
`@inherits OwningComponentBase<WeatherForecastService>`
This works fine.

In my new page I've added
`@inherits OwningComponentBase<ClientService>`
but now `Service` in `OnInitializedAsync()` is not working, I don't have access to the methods of my `ClientService`.
I managed to get it working to add
`@inject ClientService ClientService`
and use `ClientService` instead.

But I'm wondering if this is the right approach and shouldn't
`@inherits OwningComponentBase<ClientService>`
just work?

I did add the service to `ConfigureServices`:
`services.AddScoped<WeatherForecastService>();`
`services.AddScoped<ClientService>();`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? More details please.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for your reply. I updated my post. In short: I don't have access to the methods of my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OwningComponentBase` is for one specific purpose: it provides services that are scoped to the component. There's three lifetimes objects can have: transient, scoped, or singleton. Singleton is a non-issue as you'll only ever have one instance regardless, but transient and scoped don't work quite right with Blazor, because in either hosting model (server or client), things persist much longer than they would in a traditional web application.

There's a generic and non-generic version of `OwningComponentBase`. In the generic version (the one you're using currently), you get access to one scoped service (via `Service`) of the type specified via the generic type param. There's nothing really magical here. It's literally just setting an instance of `T`, the generic type, to the `Service` property, which will be disposed when the component goes out of scope (what `OwningComponentBase` is responsible for). The non-generic version just gives you access to a `ScopedServices` property, which is just a scoped service provider to pull whatever service you like from, so you can view the generic version as just using this scoped service provider to get a single service for you and set `Service` with that.

Long and short, you can throw any type you want in the generic type param, assuming it's registered with the service provider. All you've told us here is that it's "not working", so it's unclear what your issue is. More likely than not, you simply didn't register your `ClientService` via something like `services.AddScoped<ClientService>()`.

Comment: Thanks @chris-pratt  for your reply. I updated my post. In short: I did register the client, but 'Service` doesn't show me the methods of my ClientService.

Comment: That's kind of impossible. I'm assuming you actually have public methods there? Short of that, I can only think there's some larger issue with intellisense. Might need to close/reopen solution, clean and rebuild, etc.

Comment: I was creating a code snippet to post here and adding some additional comments and now it seems to be working. So it seems it was a problem with intellisense or something. Because this answer helped me the most. I'll mark it as the solution.